# Puppet - Agentless Proxy for cisco_ios devices

Tags: linux, ruby, puppet

I need Help with my puppet agentless proxy scenario.
In a fully isolated environment I installed all the modules, dependencies and ruby gems to use the puppet - puppet agent as a puppet agentless proxy for cisco ios devices.
Because this environment is isolated from the internet I had to install all the modules, dependencies and gems manually by myself and maybe I missed some change or entry the "puppet module install" command e.g. would have done.
finally I have installed all packages for using the puppet agent as an agentless proxy for cisco IOS devices I have configrued a device named EXAMPLE-DEVICE and when I run the command "puppet device -v" I get the output:

```
Info: starting applying configuration to EXAMPLE-DEVICE at file:////etc/puppetlabs/puppet/devices/EXAMPLE-DEVICE.conf

Error: Can't load cisco_ios for EXAMPLE-DEVICE: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

Maybe you can help with this :-)

Comment: Are you able to run a nslookup, dig or ping on the example-device?

Comment: Yes I can dig, ping and nslookup my device.
It seems to be that there has to be something in the /etc/services what do not exist.
Maybe the "puppet module install" writes something in this file what I missed to do.

Comment: [getaddrinfo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gai_strerror.3.html) usually refers to name resolution/network stuff. The service might not be able to access the network properly or do a lookup for example-device.

Comment: I did specified an address and a the other informations needed in the credentials like:
 address                   => 'ip-address',

   port                         => '22',

   user                         => 'uname',

   password                => 'pass1',

   enable_password   => "pass2",

Comment: I just replaced the ip address of the switch to not give the www the information about my switch :-)